# Como puedo preguntar a nivel de script(C#) en Unity en que plataforma esta corriendo el juego?

Tags: c#, unity

Quisiera desarrollar un juego multiplaforma en Unity principalmente para Windows y Android.El problema es que en Android qusiera poner controles utlizando UI para permitir al usuario interactuar con el juego ante la falta de los controles predeterminados que utiliza mi juego para Windows.Esto puedo hacerlo, lo que quisiera que estos controles hechos con UI solo aparezcan cuando este el juego corriendo en Android y no en Windows, es por ello que si puediera preguntar en que dispositivo esta corriendo pudiera saber si esta corriendo en Android y entonces mostrar los controles y de lo contrario no hacerlo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podrias evaluar hacer uso de

[Application.platform](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Application-platform.html)

para conocer la plataforma donde se esta ejecutando, veras en el ejemplo usa

```
if (Application.platform == RuntimePlatform.WindowsPlayer)
```

Otra alternativa es definir codigo de compilacion condicional segun la plataforma

[Platform dependent compilation](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/PlatformDependentCompilation.html)

algo como ser

```
#if UNITY_ANDROIDR
   //codigo
#endif
```

entonces cuando compiles generara codigo especifico

Comment: Muchísimas gracias, me ha sido muy útil y por favor disculpe si le hice perder el tiempo con una pregunta que pudiera, a su parecer, ser demasiado trivial.